# Como puedo mostrar la condicionar un resultado

Tags: vue.js, laravel-blade

quisiera saber si me podían ayudar, esta vez traigo 2 problemas.

1. en la siguiente imagen muestro una tabla con datos, esta trae la información de un stored procedure de mysql, mi duda es, en la ultima fila tiene que aparecer la palabra TOTAL en vez de la fecha '31/12/1969' estuve intentando con VUEjs pero no logré hacerlo, como podría hacer para que me mostrara la palabra "TODOS" y donde corresponde la fecha, me muestre la fecha correspondiente (como ya lo hace)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y 2) siempre con la tabla, tengo la siguiente linea de código en css:

```
<style type="text/css">
    tr:last-of-type {
    background-color: #58ACFA;
    font-weight: bolder;
    }
</style>
```

me funciona cuando el rango de fechas no excede el mes me pinta de color distinto la primera y ultima fila, pero cuando excedo en rango de fechas el mes no me pinta la ultima fila de la tabla solo el encabezado.

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Aporta mas informacion como: que seas hacer, cual es la estructura de la base de datos, cual es codigo que estas usando, y la primer imagen es un ejemplo de como debe quedar? o es la captura del error que presentas?

Comment: en la tabla aparece como debe quedar, menos la ultima fila, donde aparece 31/12/1969 debería aparecer la palabra TOTAL porque esa palabra es la que devuelvo en el stored procedure, pero al darle formato de fechas {{ date('d/m/Y', strtotime($rep->fecha)) }} aparece así porque se que es porque no reconoce la palabra TOTAL y le estoy aplicando un formato

Answer (score 0):

En que parte intentas formatear el valor recibido como una fecha? No comprendo porque envías la palabra TODOS desde el servidor. Simplemente puedes hacerlo así:

```
           <tr v-for="user in users_list" :key="user.id">
                        <td class="">{{user.name}}</td>
                        <td class="">{{user.second_name}}</td>
                        <!--                            <td>{{user.state == 'A' ?  'Activo':'Inactivo}}</td>-->
                        <td class="" v-if="user.state == 'A'">{{'Activo'}}</td>
                        <td class="" v-else-if="user.state == 'I'">{{'Inactivo'}}</td>
                        <td class="" v-else></td>
                        <td class="c">
                            <a class="btn btn-primary p-1 text-white h6"><i class="far fa-address-book"></i></a>
                            <a class="btn btn-danger p-1 text-white h6"><i
                                class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                       <td>TODOS</td>
                       <td>TODOS</td>
                       <td>TODOS</td>
                    </tr>
```

Si deseas agregar alguna lógica por alguna extraña razón puedes evaluar si estas en la ultima fila mediante el uso de una variable index:

`v-if = "users.length - 1 >=index"`

si eso es verdadero entonces muestras la final TODOS. Suerte!

Comment: Traigo 3 columnas una es donde esta la fecha otra un nombre y otra una cantidad, en la ultima fila me esta totalizando la cantidad y como es de todos los que aparecen en la lista le puse la palabra todos pero en la fecha tengo la palabra TOTAL y al darle formato me aparece la fecha que esta en la tabla, esos resultados los traigo de un stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Otra opcion es poner logica extra en una propiedad computada, para mantener la reactividad, imagino algo asi:

```
computed(){
    datosComputados(){
        let lista = this.datosReales; // Copias los datos originales en una variable
        let total = lista.splice(-1, lista.length) // quitas el ultimo item de la lista anterior y se lo asignas al total, asumiendo que esta siempre tiene el valor total.

        return {lista, total}
    }
}
```

con esto en el template puedes hacer un loop sobre la lista y al final agregar el total.

```
<template>
    ...
    <tr v-for="item in datosComputados.lista">
        <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <td>Total</td>
         <td>{{datosComputados.total.foo}}</td>
         <td>{{datosComputados.total.bar}}</td>
     </tr>
    ...
</template>
```

de manera que la logica queda encapsulada en la propiedad computada.